# azure deployment cloud service returns error Object reference after few hours

Tags: azure

Azure Cloud service deployed version works fine. But after 10 mins it returns error(Object reference not set to an instance of an object) . On restarting cloud service it again works only for 10 mins.

Comment: We would need a lot more information to try to help.  What have you done and what logs have you looked at?  What is the exact error and where are you seeing it?

Comment: I used to deploy my application from visual studio. Now I trying to deploying using azure packages. so I created a cloud service and updated in production deployment. Deployment is publishing successfully but works only for 5 - 10 mins. I'm getting Server Error in '/' Application.
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.  while clicking on sign in

Comment: @KarthickEK please add this as edit to you question. Also we'll need to see what parts of code is throwing this exception and under what conditions. What you have said so far is not enough to guess what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

If the service works fine on your local by checking your local emulator, the second place you need to check will be whether the configure tab for this cloud service (in Azure management portal) matches the cloud config file of your web/ worker role. Good luck.